# GWT - eclipse bug 346795 - PermGen space error

Tags: eclipse, gwt

After 'Check Updates' half-way download progress interruption I faced mostly the same problem as described [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=346795) and it seems like it is solved fine but I am not pretty sure what means the last comment as

> (In reply to comment #12)
>
> > (In reply to comment #11)
> >
> > > -vmargs -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
> >
> > Every option must be on its own line.
>
> Yes, this is the problem. You are running with default perm gen
>   settings because only one property per line is read.

What means

> 'Every option must be on its own line'

...in this case? I am not pretty sure how should I try to modify my ini file according to that comment and will it really help?

P.S.

Eclipse Helios 3.6
GWT 2.2

Comment: Just wondering: Why eclipse 3.6 (not 4.x) and GWT 2.2 and not 2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EACH **`vmargs`** should be in its **own** line. See the screenshot of the eclipse ini file below. NOTE **"CRLF"** is line feed char display turned on in the notepad++ editor to indicate that each vmarg entry is in a new line. If you open the file in notepad you cannot see the "CRLF" entries.

[image]

Comment: OK a little bit later I am going to test the .ini file modification and report my results

Comment: I tested the ini modification... During 2 hours of eclipse work mostly in GWT window builder mode any PermGenSpace dialogs had been shown. So that really helped I guess. Anyway, I want just remind the bug came just after the bad-luck eclipse update interruption so is there a way to reverse the update failure because it worked fine with no manual input of maxpermsize etc before?